# how to correctly use GET method in dynamic website using PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

Sorry for the very vague title, I'm not sure how to describe my problem... I'm fixing my website to make it dynamic using PHP, and I'm trying to change my side navigation bar. So when I click option 2, it changes the background color of option 2, and so on. However, I'm not so sure where to implement `foreach` to style options differently.

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
}

.flexContainer>div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebarContainer {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #dd1d5e;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #dd1d5e;
}

.sidebar a.selected {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #dd1d5e;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <?php
  if (isset($_GET['categoryId'])) {
      $selectedPage = $_GET['categoryId'];
  } else {
      $selectedPage = '1';
  }
  if ($selectedPage == '1') {
          echo "<div class=\"flexContainer\">
                  <div class=\"sidebarContainer\">
                      <div class=\"sidebar\">
                          <a href=\"category.php\" class=\"selected\">Holiday</a>
                          <a href=\"category.php\">Vegetarian</a>
                          <a href=\"category.php\">Dessert</a>
                          <a href=\"category.php\">Cultural Cuisine</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>";}
  elseif ($selectedPage == '2') {
          echo "<div class=\"flexContainer\">
                  <div class=\"sidebarContainer\">
                      <div class=\"sidebar\">
                          <a href=\"category.php\">Holiday</a>
                          <a href=\"category.php\" class=\"selected\">Vegetarian</a>
                          <a href=\"category.php\">Dessert</a>
                          <a href=\"category.php\">Cultural Cuisine</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>";}
  elseif ($selectedPage == '3') {
          echo "<div class=\"flexContainer\">
                  <div class=\"sidebarContainer\">
                      <div class=\"sidebar\">
                          <a href=\"category.php\">Holiday</a>
                          <a href=\"category.php\">Vegetarian</a>
                          <a href=\"category.php\" class=\"selected\">Dessert</a>
                          <a href=\"category.php\">Cultural Cuisine</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>";}
  elseif ($selectedPage == '4') {
          echo "<div class=\"flexContainer\">
                  <div class=\"sidebarContainer\">
                      <div class=\"sidebar\">
                          <a href=\"category.php\">Holiday</a>
                          <a href=\"category.php\">Vegetarian</a>
                          <a href=\"category.php\">Dessert</a>
                          <a href=\"category.php\" class=\"selected\">Cultural Cuisine</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>";
  }
  ?>

    <!--        <div class="flexContainer">-->
    <!--            <div class="sidebarContainer">-->
    <!--                <div class="sidebar">-->
    <!--                    <a href="category.php" class="selected">Holiday</a>-->
    <!--                    <a href="category.php">Vegetarian</a>-->
    <!--                    <a href="category.php">Dessert</a>-->
    <!--                    <a href="category.php">Cultural Cuisine</a>-->
    <!--                </div>-->
    <!--            </div>-->
```

[image]

The side navigation bar looks like this, and for example, when I click `Dessert`, I want that option to be styled differently using PHP. How can I achieve this? I tried adding

```
<a href=\"category.php?categoryId=$categoryId\" class=\"selected\">Holiday</a>
<a href=\"category.php?categoryId=$categoryId\">Vegetarian</a>
<a href=\"category.php?categoryId=$categoryId\">Dessert</a>
<a href=\"category.php?categoryId=$categoryId\">Cultural Cuisine</a>
```

here, but it didn't work. It shows multiple bars are selected... Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: PHP is serverside, you have to go to the server, you can't do it "on the fly". For that you need javascript or css on hover

Answer (score 0):

You can use your get parmeter and create separate css style files for your navigation and include them dynamically.
For example:

```
<?php
$categryId = isset($_GET['categoryId']) ? $_GET['categoryId'] : 1;
?>

...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/category_<?=$categoryId;?>.css">
```

Or if you have different nav structure you can do the same with including php file with html structure.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I want to know how to move to different pages from the current option. So for example, my sidebar is currently in "Holiday", and if I click "Dessert", it should go to "Dessert" (which changes the background color because now "dessert" is selected). But I'm not able to do so....